# missing VLC icon in Ubuntu 18.04 tray

Tags: icons, vlc, 18.04, system-tray

I recently moved to Ubuntu 18.04 from 14.04, I have a problem with VLC since I installed it, and have tried solutions from the net but didn't work out.
My problem is when I open the VC, its icon misses in the system tray! like below.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you installed vlc from repo (I am not sure if is the same for the snap) you should find the icon in `/usr/share/vlc/vlc.ico`. Check on your system if the icon is there.

Comment: @velix nope it doesn't!

Comment: Then just download an icon and place it there:
`sudo wget https://findicons.com/icon/download/202880/vlc/128/ico -o /usr/share/vlc/vlc.ico`

Comment: I cannot duplicate this issue on a fresh install of Bionic Beaver, in VM...

Comment: @andrew.46 after your comment, I suspect the installation... I've installed the VLC through `Software` app! so I have uninstalled it from there and installed via `apt` command and everything seems to be ok

Comment: The software app (ubuntu-software) will usually show the snap version over the .deb version. The snap vlc icon should show but maybe not in an upgraded install as you may be missing the app indicator snap or whatever. Atm the .deb version works better anyway..